# Alphabetizing posts in query posts / array

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, echo, posts

please can someone tell me how to alphabetize this?
I've tried quite a few things and nothing seems to work.

```
<?php query_posts( array('post__not_in' => array(46,2401), 'cat' => $category_id,'posts_per_page'=>'-1')); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        echo '<li';
        if (($ID = get_the_ID()) == $pagepostid) echo ' class="proadv-current-item"';
        //else echo ' class="post-id'.$ID.'-id'.$pagepostid.'"';
        echo '>';
        echo '<div class="sponsor-thumb">';
        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
        the_post_thumbnail( 'category-thumb' );
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
        the_title();
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    endwhile; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: are you specifying sorting?

Comment: alphabetically sort the category by name?

Comment: I would like to sort the posts by name

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying `orderby` in args array:

```
query_posts( array('post__not_in' => array(46,2401), 'cat' => $category_id,'posts_per_page'=>'-1','orderby'=>'name','order'=>'ASC'));
```

Comment: Hasn't made a difference I'm afraid :(

Comment: Do you have any other ideas?